# elastic search exception on bulk create

Tags: macos, curl, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-bulk

I want to test the bulk insert

this is my request

```
curl -PUT "http://localhost:9200/blabla/blabla/_bulk?pretty" -d '{
{"create": {}}\n
{"name" : "super"}\n
}' -i
```

I am getting this error:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 210

{
  "error" : "JsonParseException[Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for OBJECT (from [Source: [B@29ae00d4; line: 1, column: 0])\n at [Source: [B@29ae00d4; line: 1, column: 3]]",
  "status" : 500
}
```

I don't know why the error message states to close `}` i guess this is a correct JSON and i am adding the end of line as the official website asks for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the wrong sytax should not have  parenthesis after `-d`
it should be as follows:

```
 curl -PUT "http://localhost:9200/blabla/blabla/_bulk?pretty" -d '
{"create": {}}\n
{"name" : "super"}\n
' -i
```